# Cyclic dependency error TransferHttpCacheModule, LocalizeRouterModule, TranslateModule

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular5

I need the following modules for my project:

TranslateModule
LocalizeRouterModule
TransferHttpCacheModule

Somehow this combination of modules is creating a cyclic dependency.

TranslateModule with TransferHttpCacheModule - works
TranslateModule with LocalizeRouterModule - works

But when I import all three it's causing a dependency cyclic.

Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! ApplicationRef ("[ERROR ->]"): in NgModule AppBrowserModule in ./AppBrowserModule@-1:-1

Check the plnkr for reproduction of the problem: https://plnkr.co/edit/qlUQ866JzTa3JtFgSAIO?p=preview

```
@NgModule({
imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    TransferHttpCacheModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpTranslationLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
    LocalizeRouterModule.forRoot([], {
      parser: {
        provide: LocalizeParser,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [TranslateService, Location, LocalizeRouterSettings]
      }
    }),
    RouterModule.forRoot([])
],
declarations: [
    AppComponent
],
providers: [

],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
}) export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to have LocalizeRouterModule under imports since it can be injected to providers which is causing the cyclic depdendency.

Fix it as follows,

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        HttpClientModule,
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        TransferHttpCacheModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
          loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
            deps: [HttpClient]
          }
        }),

        RouterModule.forRoot([])
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        LocalizeRouterPipe
    ],
  providers: [TranslateModule  ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

**[`PLUNKER`](https://plnkr.co/edit/qlUQ866JzTa3JtFgSAIO)**

if you need a working repo, look at this as a **[`example`](https://github.com/sajeetharan/aspnetcore-angular2-universal-with-localize-router)**

Comment: I looked at your repository and see that there you are importing LocalizeRouterModule on the browser side of the Angular application. The problem i'm facing is not on the server side but on the browser. Can you give me a working plunker?

Comment: did you check the plunker attached? what do you mean by on the server side?

Comment: You attached the same plunker as I attached. I mean that in your repository I see that the app.module.browser.ts is importing LocalizeRouterModule and that app.module.ts is importing TranslateModule and TransferHttpCacheModule. This is exactly what I am trying to get working, but it's causing a cycle dependency error. Are you able to give me a working plunker?